# Watch a movie straight from Apple TV, but hear the sound on my headphones on my MB Air

Tags: mac, osx-yosemite, appletv, airplay

I don't have money for new tech or headphones. I want to watch a movie from my laptop via AirPlay (watch a movie straight from Apple TV), but hear the sound on my headphones attached to my MB Air.

Is there any way to do this??

Comment: Instead of asking a new question, edit your old one

Comment: @CanadianLuke He was right to ask a new question and delete his old one that was already trashed with two downvotes and 4 votes to close. It's not a dup if the new question solves the XY problem by asking the underlying X instead of the misguided Y, as this does.

Comment: @Spiff http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "watch a movie from my laptop via AirPlay (watch a movie straight from Apple TV)".  Those seem like 2 different things.  Do you want to start the movie on your MB and AirPlay it to the ATV?  If so, audio will be re-routed to the ATV too.  There is an option in ATV somewhere to route the audio to another Airplay device.  Note that MB's are NOT an Airplay device (they are a source).  You could use video-mirroring (if your MB supports) to send the video to the ATV, and I think you can leave the audio on the MB in this scenario.

Comment: they are not two different things.  You can mirror or extend your mac display via Airplay.  Which means you can play a movie on you mac (YouTube, Netflix, local movie file) and have it displayed on your tv.  When you mirror/extend your display, your audio also goes through Airplay.

Comment: My question stands the same. How do send video via Airplay, yet leave your sound to your mac?

Comment: You could use the app called Airparrot.